# Why is url helper in rails putting a "." instead of a "/" in path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, urlhelper

In my app I am working on allowing users to send invitations.  The invites have tokens.  And in the emails I am linking to a signup page with the token in the path.  In the mailer's controller I am using:

```
new_user_registration_url(@invitation.token)
```

as I saw Ryan Bates do in this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/124-beta-invitations).  But it appears to be outputting this format:

```
http://localhost:3000/signup.4a4aebcde29738a39c7f447f58817e49cf9b4cf4
```

Why is there a "." instead of a "/"?

Update:

I'm using devise and here are the relevant routes.  I am not to confident about these; I had struggled a little with it but these seemed to work:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get '/signup/:invitation_token' => "registrations#new", :as => :new_user_registration
  end
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations"}, :skip => [:registrations]
  as :user do
    get '/users/cancel' => 'devise/registrations#cancel', :as => :cancel_user_registration
    post '/users' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
    get '/signup' => 'registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
    get '/users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => :edit_user_registration
    put '/users' => 'devise/registrations#update'
    delete '/users' => 'devise/registrations#destroy'
  end
```

Comment: Show us your `routes.rb` to tell exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wihout `routes.rb` it's hard to tell but it seems the author has something like:

```
#in routes.rb
get 'signup' => 'controller#action', as: :new_user_registration
```

but has to have:

```
get 'signup/:token' => 'controller#action', as: :new_user_registration
```

Checking:

```
# in console
app.new_user_registration_path('ToKeN') # => "/signup/ToKeN"
```

Comment: See update. . I actually have both types of routes, perhaps that is my problem?  I am using both so that I can get a regular signup and an invitation signup.

Comment: You have 2 paths named as `:new_user_registration`, see? Comment the second one and restart your app (routing changes sometimes are too tricky to be implemented on the fly). Tell us about the result.

Comment: When I do this, the output of new_user_registration_url(@invitation.token) has a "/" as desired, but then my /signup route does not work, and more confusingly to me, neither does my users/sign_in route (get "No route matches {:controller=>"registrations", :action=>"new""}.  Any idea why?

Comment: My bad, the users/sign_in route isn't broken but the link generated by "link_to "Sign up", new_registration_path(resource_name)" no longer works.  I would like to get that working and also have both a regular signup path and one for invitation signup.  How should I do this with Devise?  May open new question.

Comment: Ok, changed the name of the invited route so it doesn't conflict with the regular sign up route and things are working fine.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that you've solved your conflicts! For the future: 1) changing `routes.rb` (especially removing things) often requires restarting your app to reflect them; 2) if quick look at `routes.rb` file doesn't help -- use `rake routes` and redirect the output to a text file -- you'll be knowing about all the routes and all the path helpers.

Answer (score 0):

If you just pass a string or a symbol as an argument to a path helper, I think it gets interpreted as the `format`. Try something like the following:

```rb
new_user_registration_url(:token => @invitation.token)
```

or

```
new_user_registration_url + "/" + @invitation.token
```

Comment: If I use the :token => @invitation.token structure, I get a url with a "?" instead of a "." which is better than where I was.  What do you mean by "gets interpreted as the format?"

Comment: @John With standard RESTful routes in Rails, you can usually add `.xyz` at the end to tell Rails what format you want the response in. The default is `html`, but you can do something like `GET /users.xml` or `GET /users.js` to get your Users index in XML or JavaScript, respectively, as long as your controller action is set up to respond to the format. You can see these options as `(:format)` if you run `rake routes`. So I think when you pass a single string or symbol argument to your path helper, it interprets it as this `format` parameter.